# What fraction of the population is married?

Tags: c++, probability

The problem below is one I came across on this [wiki page](http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=Compinvesti-prog-quiz).

> Write a program to discover the answer to this puzzle:"Let's say men
>   and women are paid equally (from the same uniform distribution). If
>   women date randomly and marry the first man with a higher salary, what
>   fraction of the population will get married?"

My algorithm:

1. Populate two arrays (female and male) with random salary values.
2. Pair a female with a random male and compare salaries. If female
   salary is less than male, increase marriage counter. Set both female
   and male `isMarried` value to true.
3. Continue dating process until maximum salary of unmarried males is
   less than the minimum salary of unmarried females.

This is my implementation:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    srand(time(NULL));


    int min = 1;
    int max = 1000000;
    Male male[100];
    Female female[100];
    double count = 0;
    bool done = false;





    //Fill array of Females and Males with random salaries ranging from 1 to 10
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        int output = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
        male[i].salary = output;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        int output = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
        female[i].salary = output;
    }


    //Start dating
    //Keep dating until the maximum salary of males is lower than minimum salary of females

    do{
        random_shuffle(begin(male), end(male));               //Shuffle array of males
        random_shuffle(begin(female), end(female));           //Shuffle array of females


        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){                              //Compare a female and male from both arrays
            if(female[i].salary < male[i].salary)
                if(!female[i].isMarried && !male[i].isMarried){
                    count++;
                    female[i].isMarried = true;
                    male[i].isMarried = true;
                    cout << "Female salary: " << female[i].salary << endl;
                    cout << "Male salary: " << male[i].salary << endl;
                }
        }

        int maxMen = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            if(male[i].salary > maxMen && !male[i].isMarried)
                maxMen = male[i].salary;
        }

        int minWomen = 1000000;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            if(female[i].salary < minWomen && !female[i].isMarried)
                minWomen = female[i].salary;
        }

        if(maxMen <= minWomen)
            done = true;


    }while(!done);


    cout << "Percentage: " << count/100;
    cout << endl;

    int unmarried = 0;
    cout << "Number of unmarried females: ";
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        if(!female[i].isMarried)
            unmarried++;
    cout << unmarried << endl;

    unmarried = 0;
    cout << "Number of unmarried males: ";
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        if(!male[i].isMarried)
            unmarried++;
    cout << unmarried << endl;

    cout << endl;




    return a.exec();
}
```

I asked this question on Programmers.SE and apparently, [I should be getting 68%](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254315/109561). 
I'm getting percentage values that range from 35% to 40%. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, eliminate salary collisions -- use a range from 1 to 1 million for 100 of each gender.  This is simply to eliminate a possible confounding variable.  Second you have women dating married men, which seems iffy (you do stop marriage).  Third, if maxMen==minWomen, you loop forever...

Comment: Okay, increased the maximum salary to 1mil. And the condition for when dating is finished (maxMen <= minWomen). Also switched the order, testing to see if both male and female are married before checking salary. I seem to be getting percentages that now range from 60% to 69%.

Comment: Also, it looks like the `isMarried` field isn't initialized, though that's hard to tell because you didn't show us the class definition. (and `Male female[100];`...?)

Comment: @T.C. That was a typo! Both classes have two members. `isMarried` and `salary`. `isMarried` is initialized to false.

Comment: Am I the only one that finds the problem statement disturbing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Your condition variable is unitialized:**

```
bool done=false;
```

THis may lead to an earlier exit of your loop than planned, because it's only set to a predicable value when `maxMen < minWomen`.

**2)  Your end condition is not set correctly:**

you have done only when `maxMen < minWomen`.  But if `maxMen == minWomen` no women would get married anymore, so you would have an infinite loop.  This phenomen is very probable if you have a small scale of salaries.  If you go from 1 to 1000, this situation is less probable. But to avoid the impossible change the clause to:

```
    if (maxMen <= minWomen)   // no new wedding in sight
        done = true;
```

Combined with the previous problem, your loop condition is wrong.  You should loop as long as it is not done  (if maxMen > minWomen, there are still wedding possible).  So rewrite it to:

```
...
} while (! done);
```

**Conclusion**

With these 3 changes, when I rerun the programme several time, I get percentages from 55% to 74%, with most values between 65% and 70%.

***Additional recommendations***

You should **avoid hardcoded numbers**.  Instead of `10`, but prefer  `max+1`.  Define at the beginning `const int N=100;` and replace all the literals `100` with `N`.  In this way it's easier to play with simulation parameters (use different salary ranges, or bigger populations).

You could put the simulation in a separate function returning the percentage as value,  and then in `main()`run the simulation a number of times (100, 1000 ?), **calculating the average of the percentage and the standard deviation**.  This gives more accurate results than manual runs and rough estimates.

If you are interested in simulations, it could be worth **having a look at [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/?kw=random)**: it provides a large choice of random generators and random distributions, much more powerful than rand().  Example:

```
    mt19937 generator(time(NULL));  // mersene twister generator seeded with time 
    ...
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);  // after declaration of your min and max
    ...
    male[i].salary = distribution(generator);   // and same for female
```

And by the way,  you may be interested in [`std::count_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/),  [`std::min()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/) and `std::max()`  which could easily save you repetitive coding of for loops.

Comment: Hi @Christophe I made these changes prior to your answer. Perhaps you were viewing a cached version of the question?

Comment: apparently it was a cached version !  I copy pasted your code, and I get percentages as indicated above, so pretty much around 68%.   Could it be that your random number genrator is flawed ?

Comment: It might be. Good advice, I decided to take an average of all the percentages from N trials and I got more or less 68% for increasing Ns. Thanks for answering :)